# Bind a directive attribute to a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that uses an attribute to build out more complex markup.

Here is the directive in use:

```
<alerts heading="Alerts {{ count }}">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="alert in alerts">{{ alert.description }}</li>
  </ul>
</alerts>
```

The directive template looks like this:

```
<div>
  <h1></h1>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the heading attribute into the `h1` so that changes to `count` update in the heading?

Comment: Assuming the directive is on the `<alerts>` tag, its attributes are made available to the directive as the third parameter of the link function (after scope and element.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may isolate your scope and use the '@' notation for gathering variables to be used for your template directive. Please also note that within your template, `ng-transclude` is mispelled.

[**Sample Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtbuoSoJIkzRjh5EGEHI?p=preview)

e.g.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
directive('alerts', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {heading: '@'},
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'alert.html'
    }
  });
```

**alert.html**

```
<div>
  <h1 ng-bind="heading"></h1>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

**usage**

```
<alerts heading="Alerts {{alerts.length}}">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="alert in alerts">{{ alert.description }} <button ng-click="remove(index)">remove</button></li>
  </ul>
</alerts>
```